# Fade in and out portions of an LED-strip at a time

Tags: arduino, led

I am having some issues with my code. What I want it to do:

- Fade in leds 0-12
- Delay 0.5 sec
- Fade in leds 13-26
- Delay (x amount)
- Fade out leds 0-12
- Delay 0.5 sec ( same as above)
- Fade out leds 13-26

What it does:

- Fade in leds 0-12
- Delay (x amount)
- Fade out leds 0-12
- Fade in leds 13-26
- Delay (x amount)
  -Fade out leds 13-26

Here is my code:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#define SENSORPIN 4
#define LEDPIN 13

// variables will change:
int sensorState = 0, lastState=0;         // variable for reading the       pushbutton status

int PIN = 6;
int totalLEDs = 26;
int ledFadeTime = 10;
int lightuptime = 7000;

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(totalLEDs, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'

  pinMode(SENSORPIN, INPUT);     
  digitalWrite(SENSORPIN, HIGH); // turn on the pullup

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // read the state of the sensor value:
  sensorState = digitalRead(SENSORPIN);

  // check if the sensor beam is broken
  // if it is, the sensorState is LOW:
  if (sensorState == LOW) {     
    rgbFadeInAndOut(255, 255, 255, ledFadeTime,0,13);   
    delay(50);
    rgbFadeInAndOut(255, 255, 255, ledFadeTime,13,26);
  }
  else {

  }

  lastState = sensorState;

}

void rgbFadeInAndOut(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue, uint8_t wait, uint8_t ledStart, uint8_t ledEnd) {
 for(uint8_t b = 0; b <255; b++) {
     for(uint8_t i=ledStart; i < ledEnd; i++) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i, red * b/255, green * b/255, blue * b/255);
     }
     delay(25);
     strip.show();
    //delay(wait);
  };

  delay(lightuptime);

 for(uint8_t b=255; b > 0; b--) {
     for(uint8_t i = ledStart; i < ledEnd; i++) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i, red * b/255, green * b/255, blue * b/255);
        if(b==1){
           strip.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0);
        }
      }
      strip.show();
      delay(wait);
  };
};
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `rgbFadeInAndOut` will fade in and then fade out the specified Leds before returning control to the calling function.

If you want your desired behaviour, just split the fade In and fade Out in two separate functions: `rgbFadeIn(...)` and `rgbFadeOut(...)`

then you do:

```
rgbFadeIn(0..12);
delay(500);   // note that 0.5 seconds is 500ms not 50
rgbFadeIn(13..26);
delay(x amount)
rgbFadeOut(0..12);
delay(500);   
rgbFadeOut(13..26);
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you for helping :)